# Understanding Class Inheritance in Python from learningPythonthehardway

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance

I have been learning Python and I finally understood what inheritance means between classes and objects. So here is my code I want to make sure I got this down right:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print self.name
    def howl(self, name):
        print "Eeh %s" % name


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, name):
        ##has-a __init__ function that takes self and name parameters.
        self.name = name
        print "%s barks and is happy" % self.name
    def sound(self, name):
        print "%s barks" % name


rover = Dog("Rover")

rover.sound("Rover")

rover.howl("Rover")
```

In order to better understand the way my classes behaved with the "base class" `Animal`, I put `print`s all over the place and I can see that `Dog` is able to call `howl`, a function from its parent class, `Animal` (Is that right?)

My other question was that when I use `rover = Dog("Rover")`, how come it's using `__init__` function call? What is the purpose of an `__init__` function when all it really does is set a value to a variable (`self.name`)? Because nobody calls `rover.__init__("Rover")`, and you can't do a `print(rover = Dog("Rover"))` and why didn't the `__init__` function of the `Animal` class print out?

Just asking for clarification here on class inheritance and function behaviors between related classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post contains multiple questions so here we go!

**1 `Dog` is able to call `howl`  a function from its parent class, `Animal` (Is that right?)**

Yes you are right.
Since you declared you `Dog` class as inheriting from `Animal` - `class Dog(Animal)` - the `Dog` class will have all attributes - including methods - declared in `Animal` hence you can call `howl` on a dog.

**2 when I use `rover = Dog("Rover")`, how come it's using `__init__` function call?**

When creating an object using `ClassName(<parameters>)` what is happening behind the scene, among other things, is that Python will call the `__init__` method defined in the class `ClassName`. For more details see [the `__init__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__), which also indicates why a class without an `__init__` method will call its parent's `__init__` method. This documentation also answer your sub-question **What is the purpose of an `__init__` function ... ?**. 
The overall idea is that you (almost) never call the `__init__` method directly.

Now for the fun part!

**3 why didn't the `__init__` function of the `Animal` class print out?**

In your code example the `__init__` method of `Animal` and `Dog` are almost similar i.e. set the `name` attribute and print something. The only difference being what they print. So let's imagine you rewrite your classes like this:

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print "I am an Animal named %s" % self.name

class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Dog, self).__init__(name) # That's the important line
        print "I am actually a Dog named %s, I bark too!" % self.name

rover = Dog("Rover")
# Output:
# I am an Animal named Rover
# I am actually a Dog named Rover, I bark too!
```

As the commend explained the import line is when we call `super(Dog, self).__init__(name)` - see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) - it will retrieve the super class of `Dog` and then we call the `__init__` method to initialize the current object `self` - hence setting `name` and calling the `print` statement in the `Animal` class.

With all this you end up with the correct calls to `print`!

Note that you have several ways to call the super class's `__init__`:

```
Animal.__init__(self, name)
super(Dog, self).__init__(name)
super(self.__class__, self).__init__(name) # self.__class__ is the class of self or its type.
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/576169/2003420) for a more in depth comparison of the various syntaxes.

Answer (score 2):

if you construct a class, you will need init funtion. 
Because your override the `__init__` function, if you don't write `__init__` function in Dog, it will use Animal's init function. If you want to use Animal's init function, you can do just like this:

```
class Dog(Animal):
    def sound(self, name):
        print "%s barks" % name
```

Comment: Oh wow that's interesting. Thank you! So that's how Python does it.